# After i deleted plugin, it is still executing in my eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, uninstallation

i have created a plugin for eclipse and created update site for it and everything. I installed on my Eclipse and it worked like a charm.
But then i want to remove the plugin.
I have tried using help>install new software>what´s already installed>click on plugin name > uninstall...

It didn´t work, the plugin is still on my eclipse.

I have tried deleting the .jar on my plugins folder...

It didn´t work, the plugin is still on my eclipse(i know that because my plugin does something when my mouse is hovering a method).

What do i do? How can I(and my plugin users) remove this plugin?

By the way, to build my plugin website, i used this tutorial:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_an_update_site_(site.xml)%3F

And uploaded my plugin on my website

Answer (score 0):

When the plugin is installed using Features:
To Uninstall a plug-in from Eclipse the usual UI way is to select About Eclipse then click Installation Details button and select the plugin you want to uninstall. Then click Uninstall button.

When the plugin is not installed with a Feature:
When you have installed it in your running Eclipse from the Plug-in Export dialog, and after as you have done deleting the plug-in from your plugins directory, you need to restart Eclipse from the command line using the -clean flag. This will rebuild the plugin cache. This is very low-level and not recommended.

Lessons:
- Always develop plugins using features

Comment: strange thing is: i used Features and i remember doing like you said: Going to "Eclipse Installation Details" page and clicking on my plugin and on uninstall... But my plugin didn´t get deleted >.<

Comment: You've already hard deleted the plugin, so best to use method 2.

Comment: thank you for your help. I think that will work, but i am developing this plugin for other people to use. If they had to go through command line just to delete my plugin, i don´t think i would want them to use my plugin. It´s best just to export the .jar and let them put it on the "dropins" folder